# awk command to count two fields using for loops

Tags: awk

I have the following file and I need to create an awk command to count how many times the field $15 (errorcode) is in each field$2 (eventkey).
so for example:

Video_load_time, errorcode: 111, number of occurrences: 2

Video_load_time, errorcode: 3805, number of occurrences: 3

app_launch_time, errcode: 111, number of occurences: 1

```
time|eventKey|Version|Model|SVersion|signal|net|State|atitude|long|subd|bupUsername|tvAccount|assetId|errorCode|errorDescription|duration

14201|video_load_time|5.7|i3|8.3|0.0|FI|GT|52.1147619|9829672936714|777|ghouso|444|6789|111|4464|7149       
4399784|playback_error|8.0|W8|33.2|0.0|FI|TED|468|071|078410X_.ca||2314831||3805|152rorDescript|0      
762|playback_error|70|ALFiee|4.2.2|0.0|IFI|AUED|4325|795|||81321761|3805|05|1529|
634|app_launch_time|5.0.0|SGHI317M|4.1.2|0.0|CELAR|AUTO_ATED|4588|64|180||||3805|yes|0     
1418|video_load_time|5.0.0.37|iP1|7.0.6|0.0|IN_HE_WIFI|AUTHEATED|45.47099941453838|477109099|||8455700500884828|111|N/A|77|9398     
1420|playback_error|5.0.0.37|iPa1|8.1.1|0.0|WIFI|BUP|9863786|6799798072||ta99|841759656|Be000|1601|Video|22
594|app_launch_time|5.0.0|S7M|4.3|0.0|CLAR|AUTO_ATED|5010226|-110.673567|6167612959947-023Xca|||111|N/A||11
421|video_load_time|5.0.0.37|iP5|8.1.2|0.0|WIFI|BUP|528950658168|06.613394189||cpcpb15|84551050401|1601|N/A||182
```

so i have created the following code:

```
awk -F \| '{ duration[$15] = $NF; ++counter[$15]; duration2[$2] = $NF; } END {for(d in duration); for(e in duration2) {print e,d, counter[d]} }'errors.out
```

but it doesn't seem to return the good numbers :(
anyone has any idea how to approach this problem?
thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the distinct pairs of ($2, $15), which is how I understand your description of the problem, you can do it like this, (although your example output doesn't seem to quite match the data).

```
$ cat vid.txt
14201|video_load_time|5.7|i3|8.3|0.0|FI|GT|52.1147619|9829672936714|777|ghouso|444|6789|111|4464|7149       
4399784|playback_error|8.0|W8|33.2|0.0|FI|TED|468|071|078410X_.ca||2314831||3805|152rorDescript|0      
762|playback_error|70|ALFiee|4.2.2|0.0|IFI|AUED|4325|795|||81321761|3805|05|1529|
634|app_launch_time|5.0.0|SGHI317M|4.1.2|0.0|CELAR|AUTO_ATED|4588|64|180||||3805|yes|0     
1418|video_load_time|5.0.0.37|iP1|7.0.6|0.0|IN_HE_WIFI|AUTHEATED|45.47099941453838|477109099|||8455700500884828|111|N/A|77|9398     
1420|playback_error|5.0.0.37|iPa1|8.1.1|0.0|WIFI|BUP|9863786|6799798072||ta99|841759656|Be000|1601|Video|22
594|app_launch_time|5.0.0|S7M|4.3|0.0|CLAR|AUTO_ATED|5010226|-110.673567|6167612959947-023Xca|||111|N/A||11
421|video_load_time|5.0.0.37|iP5|8.1.2|0.0|WIFI|BUP|528950658168|06.613394189||cpcpb15|84551050401|1601|N/A||182

$ cat vid.awk
{ ++count[$2,$15] }

END { for (i in count) {
        split(i, parts, SUBSEP);
        print parts[1] ", errcode: " parts[2] ", number of occurrences: " count[i] 
      }
}

$ awk -F\| -f vid.awk vid.txt
app_launch_time, errcode: N/A, number of occurrences: 1
playback_error, errcode: 1601, number of occurrences: 1
playback_error, errcode: 3805, number of occurrences: 1
video_load_time, errcode: 111, number of occurrences: 1
video_load_time, errcode: N/A, number of occurrences: 2
app_launch_time, errcode: 3805, number of occurrences: 1
playback_error, errcode: 05, number of occurrences: 1
```

**Note** that although awk only supports one-dimensional arrays, when you use multiple comma-separated values as an array index
awk turns them into a single index value by concatenating them
together with the built-in variable `SUBSEP` as a separator. This
lets you mimic to some extent multidimensional arrays. When iterating
through the indexes in the for-loop, however, it's up to you to pull
the values back apart using `split`.

Comment: thank you so much jas!
yes this works perfectly fine for me!
and for the split thats not a problem :)
i created a phyton to split them already
thanks again